# JSP - spring:bind and form:errors problem

Tags: spring, forms, validation, jsp

I have problem with displaying errors in JSP. Here is the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <form:hidden path="id" />

    <spring:bind path="set.name">
        <span>Set name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" required="required">
        <form:errors path="set.name" />
    </spring:bind>

    <br/><br/>

    <spring:bind path="setup.targetLanguage">
        <span>Target language:</span>
        <form:select id="target-language" path="setup.targetLanguage" >
            <option value="${category.defaultTargetLanguage.id}" selected="selected">${category.defaultTargetLanguage}</option>
            <option value="${category.defaultSrcLanguage.id}">${category.defaultSrcLanguage}</option>
        </form:select>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="setup.targetSide">
        <span>Target side:</span>
        <form:select id="target-side" path="setup.targetSide">
            <option value="${targetSide}" selected="selected">${targetSide}</option>
            <option value="${srcSide}">${srcSide}</option>
        </form:select>
    </spring:bind>
```

The command `<form:errors path="set.name" />` does not work. I don't use modelAttribute here, because I need to pass data to two objects: set and setup. It needs to be in one `<form>`. Any solutions?

Comment: That won't work. Either use the `spring:bind` as intended or use `form:` tags, don't mix. If you have 2 objects create a from wrapper to wrap them both.

Comment: How to make a wrapper?

Comment: Create an object that has 2 fields holding references to the other 2 objects.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I made the wrapper, but have problem in POST method cause I don't know how to use @Valid annotation related to wrapper (which holds two objects).

Comment: Annotate the fields in the wrapper with `@Valid`.